# Doubt about conditions of divisibility

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I was reading the solution of an exercise, which claims this:

> $$4n^2 + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{13} \iff n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 5 \iff n \equiv
> \pm 1 \pmod 5$$
>
> and
>
> $$4n^2 + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{13} \iff n^2 \equiv 3 \pmod{13} \iff n
> \equiv \pm 4 \pmod{13}.$$

Probably this is a stupid question, but i am new at this field so i am not sure how to do that, anyway, how do we go from the first equality to the second in both cases?

For example, maybe like this?:
$4n^2 + 1 = 13a \Longrightarrow n^2 = 5*(2a) + (1-3n^2+3a) ... $

But so we need to prove that $(1-3n^2+3a) = 1$?

Comment: I think, in the first congruence, there is a typo

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $ 4n^2 \equiv -n^2 \pmod{5}$ and $ 12n^2 \equiv -n^2 \pmod{13}$